# My C program is multi-threading by default or stdout reordering my print statements?

Tags: c, multithreading, segmentation-fault, stdout

I am running into a weird issue. I wrote a simple C program (two source files, relevant sections shown below). When I run the program (a.c has the `main` function), I get the output (since the number of times I am calling `process` is high, I am printing the last few print outs from the output to the screen):

```
key: 'Q'
key: 'A'
1
key: 'A'
key: 'A'
1
key: 'A'
key: 'A'
1
key: 'A'
key: 'A'
key: 'C'
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

**a.c**

```c
void process(int* hash, char* input, int number_of_ac) {
    int value, i = 0;
    for(; i < number_of_ac; i++) {
        value = get_value(hash, input[i]);
        printf("1\n");
        increment_value(hash, input[i]);
    }
}
```

**b.c**

```c
int get_value(int* hash, char key) {
    printf("key: '%c'\n", key);
    return hash[get_index(key)];
}

void increment_value(int* hash, char key) {
    int value = get_value(hash, key);
    hash[get_index(key)] = ++value;
}
```

My question specifically is (the ultimate goal is for me to try to debug why I am getting a segmentation fault on a high number of `process` calls and not on a smaller number of calls), shouldn't I see a print out like this:

```
key: 'Q'
1
key: 'A'
1
key: 'A'
1
key: 'A'
etc.
```

Why do I see a print of two letters before I see the 1 again? Is this a buffer reordering issue of my statements being printed to the screen? Or, is it somehow my C program is multi-threading behind the scene?

By the way, this exact same program runs on my laptop with a MUCH LARGER set of input:

Linux Ubuntu 3.8.0-25-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 6 20:47:07 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

But it breaks with the Segmentation Fault above on a much smaller input on another machine:

Linux x.y.z 2.6.32-279.19.1.el6.cny6.7068.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Mar 11 08:59:43 CDT 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Any ideas? I appreciate your assistance!

Comment: The compiler won't be secretly multithreading your code.  The seg-fault is a clear indicator that you've got undefined behaviour somewhere.  You're probably overflowing a buffer somewhere, but there's not enough information here; I suggest constructing a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Since `increment_value` calls `get_value` and you call each of these every time through your loop, I would not expect to see the results you are expecting to see. I would expect to see something closer to what you are actually seeing. The `printf` of the key will occur twice for every loop iteration, and the `printf` of `1` only once.

Comment: `value` is local to `increment_value`, and ceases to exist just after the `++value`. You can replace `++value` by `value + 1` with no change in behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Look how you call increment value:

```
void increment_value(int* hash, char key) {
   int value = get_value(hash, key); // calling get_value
   hash[get_index(key)] = ++value;
}
```

so you are printing a char here and you call get_value again in process function. That why you are getting multiples prints of chars before '1'

Comment: It's my mistake. I should have seen that call. I spent most of my time extracting relevant code and thinking about the seg fault that I didn't notice my own function calling get_value twice before the print of 1.